# Cannot read propery "comments" of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and trying to do my first assignment from Coursera. There is an array of objects called dishes and each dish has an array of objects called comments. I wrote my first function which simply renders the dishes and shows the image, name and a short description of the dish. As I am trying to render the comments related to each object I get the error. Folks here, asked the same question and I implemented the answer that was given and it didn't work. here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';


class DishDetail extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        ///The answer from another StackOverflow question that I implemented
        this.renderComment = this.renderComment.bind(this);
    }

    renderComment(dish){

        if(dish == null){
            return(
                <div></div>
            )
        }
        if( dish != null){
            if(dish.comments != null){
                this.props.dish.comments.map((element)=>{
                    return(
                        <Card>
                            <CardBody>
                                <CardTitle><h4>Comments</h4></CardTitle>
                                <div key={element.id} className="col-12">
                                    <CardText>{element.comment}</CardText>
                                </div>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    )
                })

        }

    }
}

    renderDish(dish){
        if(dish != null){
            return(
                <Card>
                    <CardImg width="100%" src = {dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            );
        }
        else{
            return(
                <div></div>
            )

        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    {this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)}
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    {this.renderComment(this.props.selectedDish)}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

First, you dont have to bind the functions. You can use arrow functions, for instance you can declare renderComments = () => {...} and "this" will be already binded correctly.

Second, you are passing the props as parameter into the functions. You have the props available in the whole class, you should not do that.

Third, you have cleaner ways to render things. For instance, you could do:

```
       const { selectedDish } = this.props;

       {selectedDish && <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
            {this.renderDish(selectedDish)}
        </div>}
```

And you avoid asking for null inside the method. I think the code is not working because you forgot to bind rendercomment. Try arrow functions instead.